# Proof of Erdos-Ko-Rado's theorem.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I am interested in discrete mathematics and so I have taken an elective on *discrete mathematics and combinatorics* in my $3$rd semester course.We were taught the Erdos-Ko-Rado's theorem in the last class.The statement of the theorem is as follows:

**Statement:** If $2k\leq n$,then any intersecting family of $k$-element subset of an $n$-element set has at most $n-1\choose{k-1}$ members.

But our instructor did not prove the theorem.He told us that we can do it by counting.But I am not so good in counting and I am confused.Can someone give me a proof with explanation for this theorem?

Comment: What is meant by "an intersecting family"?

Comment: @RobertShore Any two elements of the family intersect.

Comment: There is a proof on Wikipedia page for this theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Ko%E2%80%93Rado_theorem